# KeystoneJS post request does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, keystonejs

This is my view

```
form.contact-form(method="post").col-md-12
            input(type='hidden', name='action', value='notes.edit' + data.post.id)
            .form-group.col-md-12
            .form-group.col-md-12
                    label.text-center Title
                    input.form-control.input-box(type='text', name='title', value=data.post.title, placeholder='Title' required)
            .form-group.col-md-12
                    label.text-center Content *
                    .row
                        .col-md-6
                            input.form-control.input-box(type='text', name='briefcontent', value=data.post.content.brief, placeholder='brief content')
                        .col-md-6
                            input.form-control.input-box(type='text', name='extendedcontent', value=data.post.content.extended placeholder='extended content')
            button(type='submit').btn.btn-success Edit Notes
            form.contact-form(method="post").col-md-12
```

This is my post route

```
view.on('post', { action: 'notes.edit'}, function(next) {
    console.log('edit notes')
    res.redirect('/')

});
```

This is my route bindings

```
// Setup Route Bindings
exports = module.exports = function (app) {
// Views
app.all('/', routes.views.index);
app.get('/blog/:category?', routes.views.blog);
app.get('/blog/post/:post', routes.views.post);
app.get('/gallery', routes.views.gallery);
app.get('/registration', routes.views.registration);
app.post('/registration', routes.views.registration);
app.all('/signin', routes.views.signin);
app.all('/signout', routes.views.signout);
app.all('/contact', routes.views.contact);
app.all('/addnotes', routes.views.addnotes);
app.all('/editnotes/:post', routes.views.editnotes);
app.all('/editnotes', routes.views.editnotes);
```

The post request does not seem to work at all. I try console.log for the post request but in does not appear in terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending the `data.post.id` to the `value` property of your input. Thus, the input value changes to be something that *isn't* `notes.edit`. Your POST route is expecting a request with an `action` value of only `notes.edit`, therefore the POST request isn't being handled by that route.

In your Pug template:

```
 input(type='hidden', name='action', value='notes.edit')
```

EDIT:

You have a second form within your form. That may have something to do with it as well. Try removing it.

Comment: Yeah, I tried removing it but it still does not work.

Comment: Which route above are we examining? Is it set to accept all requests (e.g. `app.all(...)`? If you remove the `{ action: 'notes.edit'}` object from the POST request, does that work?

Comment: the route that we're examining is 'app.all('/editnotes/:post', routes.views.editnotes);'

Comment: Yeah, it is to accept all request like get, delete, post.

Comment: I removed the notes.edit from the jade view and what I get from the console is POST /editnotes/(title of the post)

Comment: Can you join [this chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139418/keystone-post-routing) so we can discuss the issue further?